# how to sort array to show data of countries with covid cases in descending order instead of alphabetical order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

this code is fetching data  of Covid19 statistics using API currently its showing data of covid cases of all countries in [Alphabetical order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOPDB.png) ......i want to  show data in descending order i.e country with more cases should come first in table

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.covid19api.com/summary",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.Countries);
    var sno = 1;
    $.each(data.Countries, function(key, value) {

      $("#country-wise").append("<tr>" +
        "<td>" + sno + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.Country + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.NewConfirmed + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.NewDeaths + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.NewRecovered + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.TotalConfirmed + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.TotalDeaths + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.TotalRecovered + "</td>" +
        "</tr>");
      sno++;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="country-wise"></table>
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Countries: Array(186)
[0 … 99]
0:
Country: "Afghanistan"
CountryCode: "AF"
Date: "2020-05-21T10:46:21Z"
NewConfirmed: 492
NewDeaths: 9
NewRecovered: 80
Slug: "afghanistan"
TotalConfirmed: 8145
TotalDeaths: 187
TotalRecovered: 930

Comment: this is for 1 country

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, the [`sort` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) of an array  - can receive a sort function, just use it to sort whatever field you want - BTW, this is a great project to try VueJs 

Comment: `data.Countries.sort(a => b.TotalConfirmed - a.TotalConfirmed )`

Comment: @ABDULBASIT give VueJs a try... https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/vYNbKJr?editors=1010 (if you get HTTP 429, wait a bit and try again, everyone's using `localhost` to test) ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `sort` method of `Array`.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.covid19api.com/summary",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.Countries);
    data.Countries.sort((a, b) => b.TotalConfirmed - a.TotalConfirmed);
    var sno = 1;
    $.each(data.Countries, function(key, value) {
      console.log(key + ":" + value);

      $("#country-wise").append("<tr>" +
        "<td>" + sno + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.Country + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.NewConfirmed + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.NewDeaths + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.NewRecovered + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.TotalConfirmed + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.TotalDeaths + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value.TotalRecovered + "</td>" +
        "</tr>");
      sno++;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="country-wise"></table>
```

Comment: great it worked ....i was stuck for hours...thanx alot.. now kindly help me to add option of search by country in this table.

Comment: You have to attempt it and come back if you do not know how to proceed. But I can give you a hint. `filter` function